# Simple CSV Importer for CloudKit?

Tags: ios, macos, cloudkit

CloudKit's promise is severely limited by the fact you have to write a ton of code to import your data before you can write the app you want to write that just uses CloudKit.  Anyone out there written a simple CSV importer for CloudKit?

Answer (score 0):

I put about 10MB of data into a JSON file and uploaded it through CloudKit Dashboard as an asset.

1. Add a record type such as "ImportedData".
2. Add an asset field.
3. Upload each bulk data file you need to a new record in the Dashboard using that asset field.

TANSTAAFL, you'll still need to write code to parse that data.

Tip, asset fields are also useful if you want to do a bulk download or backup of your CloudKit data through the dashboard.

Comment: I hear ya', but really it's not a solution for the amount of data I have. I am still kinda shocked Apple has made CloudKit so hard to use. Maybe a good CK importer app is my next project.

Comment: They made it that hard because of the problems they had with icloud core data. that product notoriously failed to deliver as advertised. The problem was that if you had two devices and conflicting changes were made on both before they had a chance to update each other, core data had no way to resolve the differences. In fact, its quite possible that the changes were mutually exclusive. The result was often broken core data and a broken app.